# What is the XPath filter to capture all the names under several layers element

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am querying different XML response files for various information and I must capture information from certain tags in each file. I must caption the `Name` element, however the response can have 1, 2, 3, or more layer elements with name tags.  `/:root-element/:myelement/:Layer/:Layer[*]/:Name =` this will only return the `Name` element if this is the `Name` exist at in this path.  However, some of my response files may have deeper layer levels,
`/:root-element/:myelement/:Layer/:Layer/:Layer/:Layer[*]/:Name`
If I search for `Name` in the entire document I will get unwanted information.  I only want to search for "Name" in the Layers.

Comment: *" I only want to search for "Name" in the Layers"*. Does it mean all elements -in the XPath- between `/myelement` and `/Name` must be *all* `/Layer` or it can be any element?

Answer (score 0):

In short you need to use the descendant axis.

```
/root-element/myelement//Layer/Name
                       ^
_______________________|
```

`/` has several meanings in an XPath expression depending on the context. As the first character of an location path it makes it absolute (relative to the document). It separates the parts and if the previous character is a `/` it defines the descendant axis. The full version of the expression (including the axes) is:

```
/child::root-element/child::myelement/descendant::Layer/child:Name
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Specify the node below which you wish to limit the search for `Name`
   elements, i.e:

   ```
       /root-element/myelement/Layer
   ```
2. Then use `//` (the descendent-or-self axis) to get only the
   `Name` elements under the specified `Layer` element, i.e:

   ```
       /root-element/myelement/Layer//Name
   ```

   If the context above the needed `Layer` element varies, you can abstract it away via its own `//` step, and even specify constraints on which `Layer` you want, i.e:

   ```
       //Layer[@attr = 'val']//Name
   ```